# How to Handle URL Link Tap Events using PSPDFKit for Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules, pspdfkit

I am using the PSPDFKit Module (v2.8) for Titanium Mobile (3.0.2GA) to both display cloud based and local PDF files within my App. The module works a treat (great job by the developer), however I've run into a problem.

Some of the PDF files have links to external websites within them, and when they are tapped I am getting a `No system handler registered` warning. I've checked the documentation and forums / google and cannot seem to located how these events should be handled.

Does anyone have any idea – any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you check the logs (i guess android, because iOS has integrated PDF viewers) of LogCat and check which URL they call? 'Handler' usually means the protocol (as http or ftp) but maybe these links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

Now external links are supported, so this might be a bug. In older releases there was an issue where URLs like "Http" or "hTTp" (note the uppercase) weren't properly detected. That's all fixed in the later releases (2.12 and up). Please update and let me know if this is fixed or if you're still seeing problems. Thanks!